# Can I use the same code to connect to PoWbox as Sandbox?

Tags: powbox, sandbox

Does the PoWbox service use the same protocol as Sandbox?

In particular, I'm curious if it:

- Has the same URL structure.
- Returns the same response payloads when creating/checking jobs.
- Uses the same authentication mechanism.

Simply put, can I use the same code I was using to connect to Sandbox, or do I need to make changes for PoWbox compatibility?